# Update a batch file from another batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Dear StackOverFlow Members,

Please help me with this batch file. I would like to use the answer given from the "SET /P INPUT=%=%" and have it update another batch file permanently.

This is the first batch file that runs to get an answer from the user

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
echo .................................................................
echo ..... Specify what the name of the Store is, this will send .....
echo ............... alerts to abd@abc.co.za ..............
echo ................................................................. 
echo.
pause
:option
cls
color 5E
echo. 
echo "............   Press 1 to specify what the store name is......"
echo "............   Press 2 to exit the program   ................."
echo. 
SET /P M=Type from the menu above 1 or 2 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO SEND                                           
IF %M%==2 GOTO EOF  

:SEND
cls
color 0A
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Enter Store Name: %=%                            
if "%INPUT%"=="" goto input
echo "You said that the store name is: %INPUT%"

:: Have the user confirm his/her choice
SET /P ANSWER=Is the name correct (Y/N)?     
echo You chose: %ANSWER%                                      
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={y} (goto :yes)                             
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={yes} (goto :yes)                           
goto :no
:yes
echo You pressed YES!... The name is updating     
goto name
:no
echo You pressed NO!... The program will exit
pause
cls
goto eof
:name
::set /A store=%INPUT%
echo %INPUT% >> notify_support.bat
::Terminate the program
:EOF
```

As you can see I am struggling to specify where I should "echo %INPUT% >> notify_support.bat". This is code taken from the second batch file

```
@echo off
call senditquiet -s smtp.gmail.com -port 587 -u rsupp0rt@gmail.com -protocol ssl -p access -f rsupp0rt@gmail.com -t 888@gmail.com -subject "Store ABC" -body "Hello there, There is an issue logged at the store.<br>Best regards."
```

When the first batch file runs, it updates the second one but just dumps it at the end of the file.

I need the INPUT ECHOed to replace "Store ABC" in the second batch file.

Please assist, I'm rather rusty with batch files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo %INPUT% >> notify_support.bat
```

That line contains `>>` which means 'dump at the end of the file'. You can use a single `>` to overwrite the existing file contents. That way, you can re-generate the whole file (which is only 2 lines anyway).

A different solution is to actually parse the exising file and replace that text. You can do that by using `for /F ...`, which allows you to traverse through the lines of a file. You can then generate a new file, based on the (altered) contents of the existing file. Disadvantage is that this file-parsing method is especially suitable for data files in which each line has the same format with fields and delimiters (like a CSV file). It is less suited for parsing 'complex' files like a batch file or program source file.

Comment: Hi @GolezTrol, should I then make the 2nd batch file empty and have the 1st batch file parse it. As if the 1st file is writing the 2nd one for me, using the > solution?

Comment: If you're choosing to actually parse the batch file, you will have to generate a second file which is renamed afterwards, otherwise you are overwriting the file you are reading at that moment. (Not sure about that, btw. Maybe the file is read at once when you run `for /F`.) Anyway, it's harder to implement, relies on the existance of the second file *and* relies on the existance of the `Store ABC` marker, which means that you cannot repeat the process.

Comment: So I suggest to not parse it at all. You can just overwrite it. But in order to do that, the first batch file must know exactly what goes into the second file. The advantage of that is that it's much easier to implement, and you can even generate the second file the first time; it doesn't have to exist. It may be a disadvantage that the first file needs to contain the 'template' for the second batch file, but it's up to you do decide if that is acceptable.

Comment: Hi @GolezTrol, I used echo > and just made it replace all the contents in there. I did more reading today on using for /F and it has limitations. If someone has an example of how using for /F would be interesting, I will try myself and will post here if successful. Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0):

try the code:

```
@echo off
echo Welcome
echo > echo @echo off >> batchfilename.bat
echo > echo echo hello >> batchfilename.bat
echo > echo pause >> batchfilename.bat
```

it will input the code into the batch file and when you run batchfilename.bat you will get something like:

###### hello

###### press any key to continue . . .