# How could I update values in one batch file through another batch file

Tags: batch-file

In BCP approach I need to get three values(**Machine Name**, **UserName**, **Password**) dynamically from another batch file.

**First File is look like:**

```
MACHINE_NAME=IN-L20054
DB_UserName=sa
DB_Password=sa
pause
```

**Second file is look like:**

```
bcp.exe ExportDB.dbo.AddressCountry OUT "C:\Temp\AddressCountry.bcp" -S "MACHINE_NAME" -U "DB_UserName" -P "DB_Password" -n -q
bcp.exe ExportDB.dbo.CI OUT "C:\Temp\CI.bcp" -S "MACHINE_NAME" -U "DB_UserName" -P "DB_Password" -n -q
pause
```

The need behind this is, if we run these file in **another** machine, the only thing respective person need to do is to **update** and run **first** file with there Machine Name, UserName and Password

I tried [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706269/update-a-batch-file-from-another-batch-file) but did not get succeed.

Could someone help me out here. ?

Comment: The first file is not a valid batch file...

Comment: Yeah, It could but the requirement is to set value against key, in first file. Could it be possible.

Comment: Then use the [`set`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) command; just `variable=value` cannot be done in batch scripting...

Comment: [Please see comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57946436/im-creating-a-little-game-with-java-in-intellij-like-brick-braker-but-the-tab-d#comment102306420_57946436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings can be passed from one batch file to another one either via arguments or via environment variables or via a text file.

### 1. Pass strings via arguments

**Main.bat:**

```
call "%~dp0Export.bat" "IN-L20054" "User" "Password"
call "%~dp0Export.bat" "Other Machine" "Other User" "Other Password"
```

**Export.bat:**

```
bcp.exe ExportDB.dbo.AddressCountry OUT "C:\Temp\AddressCountry.bcp" -S "%~1" -U "%~2" -P "%~3" -n -q
bcp.exe ExportDB.dbo.CI OUT "C:\Temp\CI.bcp" -S "%~1" -U "%~2" -P "%~3" -n -q
```

### 2. Pass strings via environment variables

**Main.bat:**

```
set "MACHINE_NAME=IN-L20054"
set "DB_UserName=User"
set "DB_Password=Password"
call "%~dp0Export.bat"
set "MACHINE_NAME=Other Machine"
set "DB_UserName=Other User"
set "DB_Password=Other Password"
call "%~dp0Export.bat"
```

**Export.bat:**

```
bcp.exe ExportDB.dbo.AddressCountry OUT "C:\Temp\AddressCountry.bcp" -S "%MACHINE_NAME%" -U "%DB_UserName%" -P "%DB_Password%" -n -q
bcp.exe ExportDB.dbo.CI OUT "C:\Temp\CI.bcp" -S "%MACHINE_NAME%" -U "%DB_UserName%" -P "%DB_Password%" -n -q
```

### 3. Pass strings via text file

In this example vertical bar `|` is used as delimiter which would be interpreted as redirection operator on not being escaped with caret character `^`. It is of course possible to use any other character as delimiter like `;` or `,` or a tab character.

```
(
    echo IN-L20054^|User^|Password
    echo Other Machine^|Other User^|Other Password
) >"%TEMP%\Export.tmp"
call "%~dp0Export.bat"
del "%TEMP%\Export.tmp"
```

**Export.bat:**

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=|" %%I in ("%TEMP%\Export.tmp") do (
    bcp.exe ExportDB.dbo.AddressCountry OUT "C:\Temp\AddressCountry.bcp" -S "%%~I" -U "%%~J" -P "%%~K" -n -q
    bcp.exe ExportDB.dbo.CI OUT "C:\Temp\CI.bcp" -S "%%~I" -U "%%~J" -P "%%~K" -n -q
)
```

### 4. Both batch files merged together

```
for %%# in ("IN-L20054|User|Password" "Other Machine|Other User|Other Password") do (
    for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=|" %%I in (%%#) do (
        bcp.exe ExportDB.dbo.AddressCountry OUT "C:\Temp\AddressCountry.bcp" -S "%%~I" -U "%%~J" -P "%%~K" -n -q
        bcp.exe ExportDB.dbo.CI OUT "C:\Temp\CI.bcp" -S "%%~I" -U "%%~J" -P "%%~K" -n
    )
)
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).