# I'm creating a little game with java in intellij like brick braker,but the tab doesn't move only the ball

Tags: java

The pad in game isn't moving only the ball does when i press key arrows

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        if(playerX >=600) {
            playerX = 600;
        } else {
            moveRight();
        } 
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        if(playerX < 10) {
            playerX = 10;
        } else {
            moveLeft();
        }   
    }  
}    

public void moveRight() {
    play = true;
    playerX+=20;
}

public void moveLeft() {
    play = true;
    playerX-=20;
}
```

So i was expecting that the pad will move when i press key arrows, but it doesn't only the ball starts to move when i press arrows.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen that you have twice 'KV_RIGHT'?

Comment: i guess my eyes started droping out after this time on pc, it worked i changed it. but now it the ball doesn't bounce from it...

Comment: *Again* please delete your "non" answer. As for solving your current problem, you're going to have to create and post a valid [mre] to get a decent answer without our guessing. Please read the link to see exactly what I'm requesting (it's not the entire program but rather a new small program) and why it will help you.

Comment: It would be also good to add `VK_KP_LEFT` and its counterpart `VK_KP_RIGHT` for your lucky gamers.
Can you explain to us what you this function should do?
Have you tried to write a unit test to test its behaviour? 
I personally don't get what's your variable `play`.

Comment: i runned the game several times it works fine,but now my ball bounces only from top border and doesn't bounce back from the pad

Comment: @kms: why did you edit out the image that I had edited ***into*** the question? Why harm the OP's question in this way?

Comment: I have rolled back the question to re-insert the image. @kms, please avoid making such edits in the future. You did little more than minor cosmetic edits while deleting an important portion of the question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels , sorry it was happen accidentally, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `VK_RIGHT` twice instead of checking `VK_LEFT` and `VK_RIGHT`. Basically, instead of `if left is pressed, move left; if right is pressed, move right` what you are actually doing is `if right is pressed, move right, then move left` so of course your pad isn't moving. You need to fix your if statement.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        if(playerX > 600) {
            playerX = 600;
        } else {
            moveRight();
        } 
    } else if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        if(playerX < 10) {
            playerX = 10;
        } else {
            moveLeft();
        }   
    }
}
```